# scatter graph is not displaying the date correctly for each data point

Tags: charts, date

- dates in my data set in my worksheet are all of the format da-mon-yr
- the dates range from 22-oct-21 to 11-mar-24
- the dates are sparse and repetitive.   IE :
  22-oct-21, 01-nov-22, 01-nov-22, 01-nov-22, 30-mar-24
- the y data is correct and displays correctly

the dates appearing on the graph excel displays is not correct ( the day, month, and year are wrong). IE:

00-jan-00
20-jan-00
09-feb-00
etc until the last date of
19-may-00

so it seems that the graph is not correctly transferring the dates from spreadsheet to graph (same date format).

For those people who might get hung up with why the data is the way it is, the data consists of blood work done on me. on each date, not all tests were run, so sparse data sets evolve.   also on one day 4 sets of blood work might occur at different times during that specific day.

my worksheet is arranged so that each blood test is on its own unique row. the columns
are of dates (one column for a given day-month-year). if multiple tests were run on one day, then the day-month-year date is repeated (given an additional column with same date).in a row directly below the date is the time a test is run.  For graphing purposes i am ignoring the time.

I am thus assuming excel will, for a scatter graph, space the data according to the dates, and if there are multiple data for one date, excel would display all data on that date.

please help me figure out how to get the correct date to display. Thank you.